# Does kafka connect supports kerberized DB2 connection

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, kerberos, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use kafka connect as sink and wanted to connect it to a kerberized db (db2 database) .

Does kafka connect supports kerberized db as i didnt find anything in doc.
If it accepts what will be the connection uri

I tried below

`jdbc:db2://<dbcatalogname>/schema:useKerberos=true`

Above failed saying invalid uri

Comment: which target database?

Comment: Db2, updated the post

Comment: Can someone please help on this?